# ng-change cyclic event calls each other dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have a very interesting problem. Have 2 drop-downs, with options 
0 = Exclude, 1 = Include, 3 = Only
When user want to select 3 from these 2 list, the other one should be changed to 0-Exclude. But when I try this code, its calling each other and in result the selected (3-Only) dropdown shows 0-Exclude and other 3-Only which is reverse.

Here is the code

### Controller.js

```
$scope.lockedChanged = function() {
    if ($scope.data.lockedGldata == 2) {
        $scope.data.deactivatedGldata = 0;
    }
};

$scope.deactivatedChanged = function () {
    if ($scope.data.deactivatedGldata == 2) {
        $scope.data.lockedGldata = 0;
    }
};
```

### View.html

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lockedGlOption" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Locked G/L:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control" required ng-init="data.deactivatedGldata = 0"
                    id="lockedGlOption"
                    ng-model="data.deactivatedGldata"
                    ng-options="o.id as o.text for o in lockedGlOptions"
                    ng-change="lockedChanged()">
                <option value="" disabled>Select an option...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="DeactivatedGlOption" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Deactivated G/L:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control" required ng-init="data.lockedGldata = 0"
                    id="DeactivatedGlOption"
                    ng-model="data.lockedGldata"
                    ng-options="o.id as o.text for o in DeactivatedGlOptions"
                    ng-change="deactivatedChanged()">
                <option value="" disabled>Select an option...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that when you click on first select. It listen to change of model deactivatedGlData, and in lockedChanged function, which is assigned to ng-change of this dropdown, there is mismatch. 
It listen to another dropdown, instead of self one, and that's why it's presenting in reverse.

Could you try to switch order of ng-change?

Instead of in two dropdowns in order:

```
            ng-change="lockedChanged()">
            ng-change="deactivatedChanged()">
```

Write:

```
            ng-change="deactivatedChanged()">
            ng-change="lockedChanged()">
```

Comment: Thanks @cyan. As you showed in your examples, both are same and you missed to swap the function call. But I got the idea from your answer and swap the function call and it worked as I needed. Thanks again and answer accepted.